# How to paste text from clipboard?

Tags: c++, winforms, postmessage

I have the code;

```
HWND MShwnd = FindWindowA("MapleStoryClass", NULL);
        PostMessage(MShwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x09, MapVirtualKeyA(0x09, 0) << 16);
```

which works just fine. Before hand, I copied to the clipboard a text.

What I want to know is how can I use postmessage and paste the text.

I searched everywhere and do not understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a C# code convert it or make a c# dll with my code:
(You need to add reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic`)

```
public string GetClipboardText()
{
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer c = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer();
    return c.Clipboard.GetText();
}

public void SetClipboardText(string stext)
{
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer c = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer();
    c.Clipboard.SetText(stext);
}
```

**Update C++ code :**

```
System::String^ GetClipboardText()
{
    Microsoft::VisualBasic::Devices::Computer^ c = gcnew Microsoft::VisualBasic::Devices::Computer();
    return c->Clipboard->GetText();
}

void SetClipboardText(System::String^ stext)
{
    Microsoft::VisualBasic::Devices::Computer^ c = gcnew Microsoft::VisualBasic::Devices::Computer();
    c->Clipboard->SetText(stext);
}
```

**Update 2**

I suppose that you need native code, so you didn't use my code up there that didn't require a handle, plus if you acheive `HWND MShwnd = FindWindowA("MapleStoryClass", NULL);` so you have a handle... Any way i suggest one last method is the following:

```
keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0); // press ctrl
keybd_event(0x56, 0, 0, 0); // press v
keybd_event(0x56, 0, 2, 0); // release v
keybd_event(0x11, 0, 2, 0); // release ctrl
```

Comment: I will try when I get home and if that works you will get your answer marked right.

Comment: I need it to perform the ctrl + v function using postmessage.

Comment: I tried this on handle of textbox handle and it's working PostMessage(textBox1.Handle, 0x302, 0, 0);  For Details : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/891a05ca-2d39-4f9e-9922-df69c9c2a4b1/

Comment: I sadly need it to work without a handle as I am trying to paste the text into a game's textbox. 

It works if I manually hold ctrl and click v, but when I try to use postmessage, it simply types 'v' as the ctrl button postmessage is not working.

Comment: Amen Ayach, yes I used that after I could not use your first method. Thank you for replying even though I figured it out.